# Using Word's autocorrect function to replace double spaces with single spaces

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

I'd tried unsuccessfully to use Word's autocorrect function to replace double spaces with single spaces. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://office-watch.com/2020/sentence-spacing-in-word/

Comment: You can fix it automatically with the VBA macro on this page: https://word.tips.net/T001820_An_Automatic_Two_Spaces_after_a_Period.html

Answer (score 0):

How about just a find/replace two spaces with one space?

Comment: That doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: No, but it's not a bad suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I do use the find/replace option, but was hoping there's a way to have it programmed into auto correct so it happens automatically. But not a huge issue... :-)